# PHP Class to Calculate GPA

Tags: php

I'm looking for a PHP class or script that i can use the calculate a students GPA from a Grade point scale.

Example: http://www.williams.edu/registrar/records/gpa.html

Also, need to take into account Honor and AP classes. (If class is chosen as honors assign additional .5 points to letter grade.  If chosen as AP or IB assign 1 additional point to letter grade)

---

It's not hard to re-create one myself, i'm just looking for something already pre-made i can use to save me some time.

Comment: What kind of GPA? What kind of data? Tell us some more information first… there's always (`$average_grade_base_ten/25` :P)

Comment: Need a lot more data here -- realize we have literally no idea where you are coming from.

Comment: Your link explains the math perfectly. Are you not able to code that up?  If you can't you are on the wrong site.

Answer (score 1):

1. Get a list of weightings per grade e.g (A-4,B-3,C-2 etc).
2. Sum the weightings for each grade.
3. Divide by total number of grades/courses.

Answer (score 1):

```
$score_arr = array(4.0, 3.2, 2.2);

function getGPA($score_arr) {
     $count = count($score_arr);
     $sum = array_sum($score_arr);

     $gpa = $sum / $count;

     return $gpa;

}
```

Add:  Could be modified to accept letter grades, compare via the chart, and sum scores appropriately.  The details were missing when I began the post.

Comment: What if classes are weighed differently? My classes are a mix of everything from 1 to 5 credits.

Comment: @Brendan - `(($score*$credits) + ($scoreb*$creditsb) + ...) / $totalcredits;`